# How is the org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy hooked into the web app

Tags: spring, tomcat8

Environment: Springframe 4.1.16-RELEASE, tomcat 8.03, Java1.8.0_65

Here is the (FULL) web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>mdm-project-web</display-name>

 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Remove all the .jar files from WEB-INF/lib, I can access the welcome.html in the servlet context root folder.
Adding back the .jar files, without changing the web.xml, (by the way, I've only one app deployed to the tomcat server), I get the following error in access the welcome.html:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:252)

The springframework is not hooked up in the web.xml, and I started the server fresh by deleting the temp and work directory. Why does Tomcat randomly decides to pick up DelegatingFilterProxy from the .jar file in the lib folder?